# Безопасность использования google-services.json

Tags: android, firebase, google-services, fcm

Для тех, кто не в курсе, этот файл ложиться в проект Android и хранит в себе данные для доступа к Google Firebase, возможно и к другим сервисам. Вопрос такой: насколько ли безопасно такое размещение файла? Куда авторизационные данные потом пропадают? (Ибо после компиляции программы, файл пропадает, но гугл откуда-то берёт эти данные). Собственно, хочу убедиться что никто не достанет этот файлик.

Answer (score 0):

Могу предположить что при условии закрытого репозитория и включенной обфускации кода (в вашем build.gradle `minifyEnabled true`) это безопасно.

Comment: Если кому-то нужно будет достать - достанут, так что не переживайте